# How long have the castle and its inhabitants been cursed?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

I just watched the new *[Beauty and the Beast](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2771200/?ref=m_nv_sr_1)* movie, and it differs quite a bit from the original. One difference is that Beast is already at least a teenager, rather than 11. We also see Mr. Potts (who was not caught by the curse), who does not seem to have aged much.

**In the new adaptation, how long have the castle and its inhabitants been cursed?**

Comment: The servants, while in their household item forms, don't appear to age at all in either version of the tale.  Possibly because they're not organic during that time.  Only the Beast is still organic, so ages normally.

Comment: [Since 1991](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101414/)

Comment: @Tim sure, but Mr. Potts was a villager, which is why I brought that up. And that's fine that the servants don't age and the Beast does, but we see him before the curse and he definitely is not 11.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - based on other info I've seen, it's likely to be only a few years. People often don't age much over the course of, say, 6 to 7 years.  But the real answer can only be: we don't know.  We aren't given enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Wait, Beast was 11 in the original??? I don't remember that

Comment: @Paul - The opening mention that the Beast must marry before the rose wilts on his his 21th birthday. The wilting happened at the end of the movie so the Beast was nearly 21 during most of it. While performing the song "Human again" Lumiere mention that they has been enchanted for ten years. That means the Beast was 11 years old when they all got cursed.

Comment: @BjornEriksson - Where in the the lyrics does it say ten years have passed? https://www.allmusicals.com/lyrics/disneysbeautyandthebeast/humanagain.htm

Comment: @Valorum Nowhere, because as usual i have messed things up. It is in the song "Be our guest" that Lumiere says it.
https://www.allmusicals.com/lyrics/disneysbeautyandthebeast/beourguest.htm

Comment: @BjornEriksson - Those are the lyrics for the *original* song. In the new version it says "Too long", not "Ten years".

Comment: @Valorum This was in response to "_Wait, Beast was 11 in the **original**??? I don't remember that_".

Answer (score 1):

**No more than 10 years, but probably closer to 5.**

---

If we assume that the household items age during their stint as furniture and the like, then it can not have been more than 7-10 years as that is the approximate age of Chip (Nathan Mack, the actor, is 10 years old). Since he because a cup, he was a live when it happened, and since he is no older then 10, than he could not have spent more than 7-10 years as a cup.

If we assume that the household item do not age during their stint as furniture, it really doesn't change anything as Mr. Potts is not substantially older than his wife (in the 18th century, the average age of marriage [for men was 26 and women was 22](http://umich.edu/~ece/student_projects/make_your_way/stay.htm), so there should not have been much of an age gap). Given this, I would estimate no more than 5-7 years have passed. Additionally, someone mentioned that the castle looked familiar when all the villagers were there (I don't recall who, it might have been Mr. Potts).

Technically, it could have been no more than a couple of months, since the castle was enchanted to make everyone forget about it. Roses only last about 7-14 days, but it was also enchanted and probably lasted longer than that. Also, we must remember that the Beast doesn't significantly age while in Beast form.

Ultimately, we don't know and can only make educated guesses. But from the information we do have, I would place it at longer than 5 years, but no more than 10.

Answer (score 0):

During the "Be Our Guest" scene Luminere, sorry if I misspelled his name,for ten years they have been getting rusted. Well if that the case then the Beast would have been 10 years old when he was transformed
Either way the cartoon and the movie is great.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I thought he said "too long;" can you quote a script that shows it's "ten years?"

Comment: - "*As days bled into years*", "*As the years passed*", "*It's been years since we've had anybody..."*, "*I haven't danced in years*", "*Days to years then gone*". No specifics given, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The line in the film is "*Too long we've been rusting*"

Comment: @DavidW - That line was changed between versions. In the original cartoon film he says "Ten years"

Comment: @Valorum I figured that, but the question is specifically about the 2017 version, and I checked that scene to see what the actual line was.

Comment: (But I wanted to leave my comment open to the possibility that someone had found an early script that retained that detail.)

Comment: @DavidW - Aye. The fact that the line has been changed would strongly suggest that they wanted to leave the issue open.